# Passing a function to intlinprog?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I would like to use Matlab's [`intlinprog`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html#bts3f9f-f) to optimize a cost function, but I don't know how to pass it as an input. The default `f` is double vector, but my cost function is inside another file that calculates the costs based on the input vector (of length 11) and then sums all the cost to give the total cost (which I'm trying to minimize).

Is there a way to pass my function or convert it into a vector?

Comment: If your function is not linear (the `f` in `f*x`), then `intlinprog` cannot minimize it. You can use any of the other minimizes in MATLAB, which take custom functions as input.

Comment: thanks very much, I thought there was a workaround to solve it